# How can i get the specific version of msvcr90.dll in my windows and How DLL's get into the windows folder WinSxS?

Tags: dll, windows-10-v1803, windows-10-v1809

I have a Windows 10 Pro Build 1809. I am looking for information on specific version of MSVCR90.DLL (9.0.30729.9518). I see that it is present in the path "c:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9518_none_508db366bcbd18c4\MSVCR90.DLL

- Is it possible to know, to which package this specific version of dll belong 
  to? I know it belongs to Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable, but i am not able 
  to find the specific version "9.0.30729.9518   ".
- How does the files get into WinSxS folder? Does the applications which we 
  install copies the file to this folder or any Windows Security Updates or is 
  that the files are present when the OS itself is installed.

Furthermore, i am not able find these specific version of dll in WIndows 10 Pro Version 1803. So i need help on how can i get this specific file on my v1803 system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that specific msvcr90.dll, you will need to install Windows 10 Pro Build 1809 and copy Visual C++ 2008 DLLs from that folder. I don't see a way to download the equivalent from existing Microsoft downloads.

I checked Visual C++ 2008, 2008 SP1, and [2008 SP1 w/ MFC update.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368

The most recent one I could find was 9.00.30729.6161 for x86 (32-bit).

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update

[image]